# how to set HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY in EKS Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, http-proxy

how to set HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY in EKS Cluster?

I set HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY in pod, for connecting to proxy server ip
but, it doesn't work.

Do i need to set these variables in EKS Cluster?

help me please!

And is it right that the network is connected in the order below?
pod -> worker node -> EKS cluster -> vpc nat ip ---(HTTPS_PROXY)----> proxy server

help me please!

Comment: Have you configured [NetworkPolicy allow-all-egress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#allow-all-egress-traffic)?

Comment: You might want to try to use a configmap in the kube-proxy and aws-node DaemonSets as suggested in [Alex's Blog](https://www.arhea.net/posts/2020-06-16-kubernetes-http-proxies).

Comment: @SaschaDoerdelmann  yes! i enrolled outboud any open! thank you for the reply